# Cloud Run inter-service communication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Consider two GCP Cloud Run services that communicate with each other.

Their URLs will look like follow:

- `http(s)://service1-gcphash.a.run.app/`
- `http(s)://service2-gcphash.a.run.app/`

Note the DNSs of these urls are public, and if the permissions allow, may be accessed from the outside world.

Now, imagine these two service communicate with each other, my questions are:

1. If one service calls directly the other service, will the request be routed ONLY in the internal GCP network or is it possible that it will pass through the outside world?
2. In case the request stays only inside the GCP network, does it make sense to be encrypted via https, or will http request be secure enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If one service calls directly the other service, will the request be
> routed ONLY in the internal GCP network or is it possible that it will
> pass through the outside world?

Network traffic between Google services stays on Google's private backbone.

> In case the request stays only inside the GCP network, does it make
> sense to be encrypted via https, or will http request be secure
> enough?

If you attempt to connect via HTTP, Cloud Run will send an HTTP Redirect with an HTTP Location header set to a secure URL (HTTPS).