# How to run a GCP Cloud run that calls another GCP Cloud Run for data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

I have two cloud runs within the same VPC/Project, which one cloud run (A) builds the request based upon the output of the request of another cloud run (B).

I am calling cloud run (B) from cloud run (A) by providing cloud run (B)'s trigger URL in cloud run (A)'s `.env`.

The error from the `curl` I receive, is "System Unavailable".
The error logs from the cloud run is:

```
POST 503
"The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#malformed-response-or-connection-error"
```

The logs show that the cloud run (A) is successfully calling the other cloud run (B). But the request takes up to 60-120 seconds until a response is generated by cloud run (A). I set the request timeout to 10min on cloud run (A) to be safe but still face errors on cloud run (A).

The only network specific non-default setting used when setting up both cloud runs is "Ingress=Internal+load balancing".

This setup works with the original reference cloud run (B) is sent a request from a GCE VM server running the same image+container setup.

What cloud run setting(s) do I need to get one cloud run to be able to request data from another properly?

I am referencing the cloud run from both another cloud run and vm server via its trigger url:

`cat .env`

`URL=https://<name>.a.run.app`

Comment: Cloud Run is not internal to your VPC. Compute Engine is. Are you calling the other Cloud Run instance via the load balancer URL or the Cloud Run generated URL? Edit your question with details.

Comment: I see...I updated but not sure I made it any clearer.
I am referencing cloud run (B) via the cloud run generated url and including the url in cloud run (A)s .env. There is no load balancer, I just changed it to this setting "Ingress=Internal+load balancing" because I thought it might help (it didn't) and internal works for my minimum use-case normally.

Comment: Your last edit indicates the problem. You have set **Ingress=Internal+load balancing**. Cloud Run is not internal to your VPC as I indicated in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry I am confused by what you mean by internal. Are you saying what I would like to do, is only possible if I put a LB infront of cloud run (B)?

Comment: The setting **internal** means from your VPC. The other Cloud Run instance is not part of your VPC, therefore it is external and will be blocked.

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I see what you mean by additional details.
Both cloud run(A) + (B) are within the same VPC/project.

Comment: After your edit. You still do not understand. Neither Cloud Run instance is part of your VPC, they are part of Google's network. If you enable **internal** they cannot network with each other.

Comment: Ah now I understand, thank you for taking the time to explain it to me!
Cloud run (A) must be allowed access to public internet via ingress=all, is what your saying is only possible?

Comment: There are many ways to access a Cloud Run endpoint. Your configuration prevents access.  Unless you understand what **internal** means, do not use it for public access. Protecting a Cloud Run instance should be via authorization and not network location.

Comment: @Matt-Block-Farms.io Does john's statements solves your problem?

Comment: John's statement did help. The answer I was seeking was assuming my question was possible with those network restrictions but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Hanley explained in the comments, my answer also focused around the same points.

For your service(B) to be called by service(A) these are the conditions you must be met:

- Make sure both services are deployed under the same VPC network and both services should be in the same project. For more information a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352749/20239914) has explained these constraints.
- For Cloud Run inter-service communication follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189635/cloud-run-inter-service-communication) which answers some of your questions